# how to make relation between table and array of ids from another table laravel

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

i have 2 tables, stores and products

stores table has field called `products_ids`

in this case i am saving the products in the stores by their ids in `products_ids` field as an array like this `[1,2,3,4,5]` i know it's not good practice to do it like this but this is the situation.

how can i make a relation in the model to achieve thing like this

```
Store::with('products')->get();
```

thanks

Comment: Are you able to change the structure to better practice? Ie. adding a store_id field to products instead of the product_ids in the store or making it a many-to-many relation by adding a table in between.

Comment: @Teun sorry but structure unchangeable

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would work for you, but try it anyway:

in your **Store model** add the following:

```
public function products ()
{
    return Product::whereIn('id', $this->products_ids)->get();
}
```

Comment: what does it say?